# storing ref to attribute not value into list

Tags: python, class

I was wondering how to bind an attribute of an instance of a class into a list.

For example, I have a class that stores attribute into a dict and I use **getitem** and **setitem** to edit this dict. The issue is that the dict only stores the values of the attribute not a ref or pointer to the attribute, then when I change the value in the dict with **setitem** that doesn't update the value of the attribute only the value in the dict.

```
class Test:
def __init__(self):
    self.a = 4
    self.data = {'a': self.a}
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.data[key]
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self.data[key] = value
```

which lead to my problem :

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t['a']
4
>>> t['a'] = 3
>>> t.a
4
```

So is there a way to store a reference to the attribute instead of its value so I can use **set** or something similar? I'm not quite familiar with **getattribute** and those methods so help would be appreciated.

Comment: but why? `self.__dict__` is doing pretty much the same

Comment: @DeepSpace can I do self.__dict__(key) = value ? It doesn't work for me

Comment: @Apo You are doing `self.data[key]`, so why `self.__dict__(key)`? Try `self.__dict__[key]` **However**, you should not change it. Just do `t.a = 1` and check `t.__dict__`

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes it works. That's a go-around but I'm really looking for a way to store a reference (a pointer like) into the values of my dict. I know when I create multiple plot with pyplot I can store each in a list and access it later, I'd like to do the same here.